# Finding the solutions using pyomo and gurobi

Tags: gurobi, pyomo

I have a code that uses pyomo and gurobi but when i try to run it, it doesn't give me the optimal solutions, just says that they exist. What can i do?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Please post the code and output as text to improve readability and searchability.